# NGXS - Provided invalid object while return of(any) in switchMap

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angularfire2, ngxs

I have an action that gets from firebase's authState the user. If the user exists, then the code returns the document related to the user. If not, `of(null)` would be returned:

#### class AuthState

```
ngxsOnInit({dispatch}: StateContext<AuthStateModel>) {
  dispatch(SyncAuth);
}

@Action(SyncAuth)
syncAuth({dispatch}: StateContext<AuthStateModel>) {
  return this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
    switchMap(fireAuth => fireAuth ? this.authService.auth$(fireAuth.uid) : of(null)),
    tap(user => dispatch(new PatchUserData(user)))
  );
}
```

#### class AuthService

```
auth$(userId: string): Observable<User> {
  if (!userId) {
    return of(null);
  }

  return this.db.doc$(`users/${userId}`).pipe(
    map(user => user ? this.transform({...user, id: userId}) : null),
    shareReplay(1)
  );
}
```

Looks simple, right? Well, it's not going to work, unless your Redux Devtools plugin is on (Yeah, I know it's weird).

When I want to return an observable with a value of any type (such as number, string, null or even undefined), inside the switchMap operator, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable. (zone.js:192)
>
> ```
> at subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:41)
> at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:6)
> at SwitchMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/switchMap.js.SwitchMapSubscriber._innerSub (switchMap.js:47)
> at SwitchMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/switchMap.js.SwitchMapSubscriber._next (switchMap.js:40)
> at SwitchMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
> at angularfire2.js:49
> at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
> at Object.onInvoke (core.js:3820)
> at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:387)
> at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:138)
> ```

The problematic line is in my `AuthState` class:

```
// fireAuth === null
switchMap(fireAuth => fireAuth ? this.authService.auth$(fireAuth.uid) : of(null)),
```

But, if I remove the `of` operator and return the result of `authService.auth$` observable (which returns `of(null`), then the error's gone:

Comment: would you mind adding the explicit imports that you use in both your service class and authState class?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo you're a wizard. My IDE imported `of` from `rxjs/internal/observable/of`instead of `rxjs`. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thought so. Np.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, we put lots of trust in our IDEs. Sometimes we shouldn't. My IDE imported the operator this way:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/internals/operators';
```

instead of

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```

Comment: When using rxjs 6, you would normally import from only two places. 'rxjs/operators' for all pipeable operators. 'rxjs' for creation and all other types. There are other import paths but there not commonly used - https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md.

Comment: @kctang Yeah, I know. But the thing is that I didn't import manually, my IDE imported it. To prevent another future incorrect import for rxjs, I had to disable an option in the settings